# Trouble with using iloc in pandas dataframe with hierarchical index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm getting this ValueError whenever I try to give a list to iloc on a dataframe with a hierarchical index.  I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug.  I haven't had any issues using iloc the same way with a non-hierarchical index.  This is using Pandas 0.12.0.

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
            D         E         F
a x -1.050681 -0.084306 -1.635852 
  y  1.544577  1.594976 -0.084866
b x  0.462529 -1.873250  1.252685
  y -0.468074  0.673112 -0.900547
c x  0.901710 -0.432554  0.260157
  y  0.101522 -0.550223  1.389497

In [26]: df.iloc[[1,3]]
..... snip .....
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'

In [27]: df.iloc[range(2)]
...... snip .....
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'
```

Comment: I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5529) and has been fixed in master (0.13), a temporary workaround is to use ix (!):

```
In [11]: df1.ix[[1, 3]]
Out[11]: 
            D         E         F
a y  1.544577  1.594976 -0.084866
b y -0.468074  0.673112 -0.900547
```

In master, 0.13:

```
In [12]: df1.iloc[[1, 3]]
Out[12]: 
            D         E         F
a y  1.544577  1.594976 -0.084866
b y -0.468074  0.673112 -0.900547
```

Comment: awesome, thanks, I searched tracker, but haven't found it. and forgot ix method too :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that pandas can't convert `[[1,3]]` to a proper MultiIndex. You might want to fill a bug in pandas [issues tracker](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues). The only workaround I found is to construct it manually, this way it is passed as is.

```
>>> tup = zip(*[['a','a','b','b'],['x','y','x','y']])
>>> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tup, names=['f','s'])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4))
>>> df
            0         1         2         3
f s
a x -0.334280  0.479317 -0.358416 -0.245807
  y  1.279348 -0.096336  0.100285  0.037231
b x -0.368452  0.219868 -0.103722 -0.575399
  y -0.813583 -0.042694  0.897361  1.636304
>>> idx = [i in [1,3] for i in range(len(df.index))]
>>> idx
[False, True, False, True]
>>> df.iloc[idx]
            0         1         2         3
f s
a y  1.279348 -0.096336  0.100285  0.037231
b y -0.813583 -0.042694  0.897361  1.636304
```

Other ways is to use `get_level_values` to access `MultiIndex` by level

```
>>> df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('f') == 'a']
            0         1         2         3
f s
a x -0.334280  0.479317 -0.358416 -0.245807
  y  1.279348 -0.096336  0.100285  0.037231
```

On contrast, slice is correctly converted to MultiIndex:

```
>>> df.iloc[0:2,:]
           0         1         2         3
f s
a x -0.33428  0.479317 -0.358416 -0.245807
a y  1.279348 -0.096336  0.100285  0.037231
```

Comment: I need to access a list of non-contiguous row numbers though.  I'm able to do that with iloc if the dataframe index isn't hierarchical.  But with hierarchical indices, I get the error I mentioned.  Is this a known Pandas bug?

Comment: @user2205 don't know. added the only w/around I found to the answer